# Counting matches in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm writing a basic search engine going against an internal data warehouse.

Suppose I have a 'skills' table, like this:

```
EmpID  Skills
-----  --------------------
    1  ,Java,
    2  ,Java,,C#,
    3  ,C#,,Ruby,
    4  ,Java,,C#,,Python,
    5  ,Python,,C#,
```

I need to write a query that searches the skills table, looking for matches.

If I'm searching for Java **AND** C#, I would like to see these results:

```
EmpID  Skills             Matches
-----  -----------------  -------
    2  ,Java,,C#,               2
    4  ,Java,,C#,,Python,       2
```

If I'm searching for Java **OR** C#, I would like to see these results, ordered by Matches:

```
EmpID  Skills              Matches
-----  ------------------  -------
    2  ,Java,,C#,                2
    4  ,Java,,C#,,Python,        2
    1  ,Java,                    1
    3  ,C#,,Ruby,                1
    5  ,Python,,C#,              1
```

How could I write that query in SQL (Oracle 11)?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to provide the "user inputs" (the skills to be matched, and the choice of "OR" vs "AND" etc?) What choices similar to AND and OR should there be available when you input three skills to search for, or four skills? Just the number of skills?

Comment: We have a predefined list of skills, and show those in a multiple-select list.  The user can also check a box to make all skills required (AND), or leave it unchecked (OR).

Comment: Oh - so you will look for either ALL skills, or ANY ONE of the skills - not other combinations. Then in the solution I provided (which works for the OR choice, ANY ONE skill matched), you can get the AND version (ALL skills matched) by adding a WHERE clause in an outer select - selecting only the rows where the number of matches is equal to the total number of skills.

Comment: The greatest help in your DB, though, will come from normalizing your data. The table structure violates first normal form - instead, you should have a table with columns empid and skill, and have several rows for the same empid if she or he has several skills. Then all queries against the table will be a lot easier to write, read and maintain, AND they will run a lot faster.

Comment: I agree about the table structure. Unfortunately, I don't own the table, I'm just a user of the data.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case way too often. We must play the hands we're dealt....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with
     test_data ( empid, skills ) as (
       select '1', ',Java,'             from dual union all
       select '2', ',Java,,C#,'         from dual union all
       select '3', ',C#,,Ruby,'         from dual union all
       select '4', ',Java,,C#,,Python,' from dual union all
       select '5', ',Python,,C#,'       from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SOLUTION BEGINS BELOW
select empid, skills, 
       case when skills like '%,Java,%' then 1 else 0 end +
       case when skills like '%,C#,%'   then 1 else 0 end as matches
from test_data
order by matches desc, empid   --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

Comment: Depending on your requirements and, I like the simplicity of this answer. If you need it to be a little more robust, consider a simple REGEX instead. `CASE WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(x,'(,|^)Java(,|$)') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Also, to use this in the AND scenario, simply filter with `WHERE matches = 2`.

Comment: @HepC - in a more robust setup (as robust as it can be, when the base data is not even in first normal form), the inputs (skills to search for) would be given in a helper table, and the solution would do a join instead of the manual count... but that's another story.

Comment: @HepC - regular string functions (LIKE, INSTR etc.) should be preferred to regexp whenever possible - they are faster. Also, there is regexp_like, no need for regexp_instr, and the matching pattern can be much simpler - in the OP's setup, ALL tokens are surrounded by commas, even the first and the last one.

Comment: I think mathguy's solution will get me what I need.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mathguy I agree with the points you make here. However, there are inherent limitations. If you need to search for "Java" and "Javascript" as separate skills, you need to ensure you are comparing the entire token - therein lies the value of using regex. As for modeling concerns, I don't think that is in scope of the question; making it more robust within the current model is what I was referring to.

Comment: @HepC - I meant you don't need `(,|^)Java(,|$)`, you just need `,Java,` - you don't need the anchors, you do still need the commas around the skill name.

Comment: @mathguy Good point! I'm just used to being more defensive about that sort of thing. With a bad design such as this, I assume inconsistency in format. But based on the sample data, the simpler pattern is the better fit for easy readability.